# Ransack sort_link for foreign attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I have a belongs_to relationship and I'm showing the name of the user is this instance.

But I would like to sort by user name.

```
<th><%= sort_link @q, :user_id %></th>
```

How would I go about sorting by the user name rather that user.id?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question lacks some necessary details, so I am guessing many things.

First did you try:

```
<th><%= sort_link @q, :user_name %></th>
```

Or if your user name column name is username:

```
<th><%= sort_link @q, :user_username %></th>
```

Here 'user' before '_' is the name of user table(model).

You may need to edit the controller to change

```
@q = YourModel.search(params[:q])
```

into

```
@q = YourModel.joins(:users).search(params[:q])
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't realise I could traverse the objects like that.

Comment: I can not see it in the documentation. I must have overlooked.